# Dots and boxes solving algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm currently working on a "[dots and boxes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_and_Boxes)" program where the input is automatically generated by a computer, and our output is what move we'll make.  I'll be competing against another player (their algorithm).

I'm representing the dots and boxes board as a matrix in Python.  Winning the game is top priority: algorithm efficiency is not that important.

Is there a best, not complex algorithm for automatically figuring out what move we should make, given a board?

P.S. - You don't need to give me anything in code if you want...English algorithms are perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This game is [**zero sum game**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero%E2%80%93sum_game), so I'd suggest using the [**min-max algorithm**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax) for it. This algorithm was used by [deep-blue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_Blue_%28chess_computer%29) to win Kasparov in chess.

Create your heuristic function, which evaluates each state of the game, and use it as the evaluation function of min-max algorithm.

You can also improve min-max by using [alpha-beta prunning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha-beta_pruning).

The idea of min-max is to **exhaustively search all possible moves** [up to certain depth usually, since the states you need to go over is exponential in the number of depth], and chose the best move, assuming your oponent is also going to make his best possible move.

p.s.

> Winning the game is top priority: algorithm efficiency is not that
>   important.

They are strongly connected together, since the more efficient your algorithm is, you will be able to check the possible solutions up to better depth, and the better chances you will have to win. Note that with unlimited time, you can explore the whole game tree and come up with a winning strategy from each game state. However - exploring the whole game-tree is probably unrealistic.

Comment: This is a great suggestion, but seems too complex for my project.

Comment: @CaseyPatton: then you will with 100% probability lose out to a program which does this, unless there is a known heuristic for this game which perfectly dictates optimal play. Even a brute-force search implies doing this.

Comment: @CaseyPatton: This is practically the best and most used algorithm for all zero-sum games. **The difference between agents now-days are the heuristics used, and not weither to use it or not**. Also, I believe you can find an existing implementation for it on python on-line, and implementing the min-max algorithm is not that hard anyway.

Comment: @CaseyPatton it sounds complex, but it can be really simple. All you need is a function to evaluate your position in a given game configuration. It can be the number of box you have minus the number of opponant's box. Then build the possible moves from your position and compute the path that maximize the quality of your position. Then take this path. Once you have a simple implementation, you should try to improve the state evaluation function, and try to optimise your tree to avoid computing useless pathes.

Comment: Um this answer doesn't contain any code for me to copy paste why is it at the top

Answer (score 24):

I think that minimax is not the best choice of algorithm for dots-and-boxes. For the full story about this game you really need to read the book [*The Dots and Boxes Game: Sophisticated Child's Play* by Elwyn R. Berlekamp](http://math.berkeley.edu/~berlek/cgt/dots.html), but I'll give you a brief summary here.

Berlekamp makes a number of powerful observations. The first is the *double-cross strategy*, which I assume you know about (it's described in the [Wikipedia page on the game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_and_Boxes#Strategy)).

The second is the *parity rule for long chains*. This follows from three facts about the majority of well-played games:

1. The long chains will be played out at the very end of the game.
2. There will be a double cross in every chain except the last one.
3. The player who first has to play in any long chain loses the game.

plus the constraint that the number of dots you start with, plus the number of double-crosses, equals the number of turns in the game. So if there are sixteen dots to start with, and there is one double-cross, there will be seventeen turns. (And in the majority of games, this means that the first player will win.)

This simplifies the analysis of mid-game positions enormously. For example, consider this position with 16 dots and 11 moves played (problem 3.3 from Berlekamp's book). What's the best move here?

[image: Berlekamp problem 3.3]

Well, if there are two long chains, there will be one double cross, the game will end after another six moves (16 + 1 = 11 + 6), and the player to move will lose. But if there is only one long chain, there will be no double cross and the game will end after another five moves (16 + 0 = 11 + 5) and the player to move will win. So how can the player to move ensure that there is only one long chain? The only winning move sacrifices two boxes:

[image: The winning move]

Minimax would have found this move but with a lot more work.

The third and most powerful observation is that dots and boxes is an [*impartial game*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impartial_game): the available moves are the same regardless of whose turn it is to play, and in typical positions that arise in the course of play (that is, ones containing *long chains* of boxes) it's also a [*normal game*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_play_convention): the last player to move wins. The combination of these properties means that positions can be analyzed statically using [Sprague–Grundy theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprague%E2%80%93Grundy_theorem).

Here's an example of how powerful this approach is, using figure 25 from Berlekamp's book.

[image: Dots-and-boxes position with a long chain]

There are 33 possible moves in this position, and a well-played game lasts for around 20 more moves, so I'd be surprised if it were feasible for minimax to complete its analysis in a reasonable time. But the position has a *long chain* (the chain of six squares in the top half) so it can be analyzed statically. The position divides into three pieces whose values are [*nimbers*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nimber):

[image: Position analyzed into nimbers]

These nimbers can be computed by dynamic programming in time O(2<sup>*n*</sup>) for a position with *n* moves remaining, and you will probably want to cache the results for many common small positions anyway.

Nimbers add using exclusive or: *1 + *4 + *2 = *7. So the only winning move (a move that reduces the nim-sum to *0) is to change *4 to *3 (so that the positions sum is *1 + *3 + *2 = *0). Any of the three dotted red moves is winning:

[image: Winning moves]

---

Edited to add: I'm aware that this summary doesn't really constitute an *algorithm* as such, and leaves lots of questions unanswered. For some of the answers you can read Berlekamp's book. But there's a bit of a gap when it comes to the opening: chain counting and Sprague–Grundy theory are really only practical in the mid- and endgame. For the opening you'll need to try something new: if it were me I'd be tempted to try [*Monte Carlo tree search*](http://senseis.xmp.net/?MonteCarlo) up to the point where the chains can be counted. This technique worked wonders for the game of Go and might be productive here too.

Comment: +1 for answering the question. Lovely answer. I've only met the double cross when my cousin and I played as kids.

Comment: This answer is gold. Many, many, many things for me to learn. Wikipedia, I'm coming baby.

Comment: Nice. There are also some useful stuff about Dots-and-Boxes strategy and the relation to Combinatorial Game Theory in this site: **[http://wccanard.wetpaint.com/](http://wccanard.wetpaint.com/)**

Comment: Sprague–Grundy theory is not applicable here, since players
win at Dots and Boxes by having the highest score. The last player to move will lose if his score is less than score of his opponent.

Comment: @angelvet: See the "third observation" in my answer, which explains that most positions of Dots and Boxes have long chains and so are "normal" meaning that the last player wins. That's why Sprague–Grundy theory is applicable to these positions.

Answer (score 5):

I think [Gareth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/68063/gareth-rees)'s answer above is excellent but just to add (I don't have any reputation to add comments) that Dots and boxes has been shown (at least with a sketch) to be np-hard according to this:  [arxiv.org/pdf/cs/0106019v2.pdf](http://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/0106019v2.pdf)

I wrote a javascript version of dots and boxes that tries to incorporate the strategies mentioned above [dotsandboxes.org](http://dotsandboxes.org). It's not the best one available (doesn't yet incorporate all techniques that Gareth mentions) but the graphics are nice and it beats most humans and other implementations :) Feel free to have a look at the code and there are some other links to other people's version of the game you can train yours on.